# Sequelize infinitely executing INSERT on error

Tags: sequelize.js, hapi.js

I am executing the following lines of code to insert a User into my application;

```
models.User.create({
    emailAddress: request.payload.emailAddress,
    hashedPassword: request.payload.password,
  }).then(function (user) {
    return models.X.create({
      membershipExpires: moment(),
      userId: user.id
    }).then(function (x) {
      return models.ContactDetails.create({
        userType: 'X',
        userId: x.userId,
        city: request.payload.contactDetails.city,
        postcode: request.payload.contactDetails.postcode
      }).then(function () {
        if (!user.sendWelcomeEmail())
          console.log('sent welcome email yoo');

        return reply("User created!");
      })
    })


  }).catch(function (error) {
    return reply(Boom.badRequest('Validation error'))
  })
});
```

when this fails due to a unique constraint on the email field, the insert is repeatedly executed until I kill the process. It is trying to insert a new User with each iteration, as the bcrypt hashedPassword field differs.

Why is this happening? I am using HapiJS with Sequelize on Node 5.7

Comment: You are not catching promise errors which probably get swallowed by domains.

Comment: @simon-p-r Updated question code

Comment: I don't use promises but that code does not look right?!

Comment: You need to provide more context, we need to see the entire function that contains this code. There is no error that I can see in the code you provided, at least there is nothing that would ever cause it to loop like that since if an error occurrs in any of the blocks the promise is rejected and the rest isn't executed. On an unrelated note, i recommend using a transaction so if the second or third blocks fail, everything is rolled back. http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/transactions/